Spring boot support for liquibase
I am uplifting my project from spring boot 2.7.18 to 3.2.7 and we were able to make most of the things up and running. We have overriden liquibase version to 3.8.9 and we are getting
liquibase.exception.UnexpectedLiquibaseException: liquibase.exception.ServiceNotFoundException: liquibase.exception.ServiceNotFoundException: Could not find unique implementation of liquibase.executor.Executor.  Found 0 implementations

Does anyone know if liquibase 3.8.x still supported in spring boot 3.2.x version?
I tried to debug a bit and it seems uplifting to 4.24.x does resolve this issue. But it had some multi threading issues that will make more issues.
Full stack Trace:
liquibase.exception.UnexpectedLiquibaseException: liquibase.exception.ServiceNotFoundException: liquibase.exception.ServiceNotFoundException: Could not find unique implementation of liquibase.executor.Executor.  Found 0 implementations
at liquibase.executor.ExecutorService.lambda$getExecutor$0(ExecutorService.java:30) ~[liquibase-core-3.8.9.jar!/:na]
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1708) ~[na:na]
at liquibase.executor.ExecutorService.getExecutor(ExecutorService.java:24) ~[liquibase-core-3.8.9.jar!/:na]
at liquibase.database.AbstractJdbcDatabase.getConnectionSchemaName(AbstractJdbcDatabase.java:359) ~[liquibase-core-3.8.9.jar!/:na]
at liquibase.database.AbstractJdbcDatabase.getDefaultSchemaName(AbstractJdbcDatabase.java:324) ~[liquibase-core-3.8.9.jar!/:na]
at liquibase.changelog.ChangeLogParameters.<init>(ChangeLogParameters.java:61) ~[liquibase-core-3.8.9.jar!/:na]
at liquibase.Liquibase.<init>(Liquibase.java:110) ~[liquibase-core-3.8.9.jar!/:na]


please share your pom xml or build gradle or you know what Iean

Spring Boot 3.x does not support Liquibase 3.x. You should, ideally, use the Spring Boot-managed version of Liquibase. With Spring Boot 3.2.7 that's Liquibase 4.24.0. Other 4.x versions of Liquibase may also work with Spring Boot 3.2.7 but it will depend on whether or not any breaking changes have been made in Liquibase. You would have to try them and see.

As said by Andy Spring Boot 3.2 supports Liquibase 4.24.
You can see that in this release notes URL of Spring Boot 3.2 
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-3.2-Release-Notes
